# Fail to Import View from main Django project folder into app views.py

Tags: python, django

I have a problem to import a view from the main Django project views.py into my app's views.py.

This is what happens:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'index' from 'ebdjango.views'
>   (/Users/iamsuccessful/ebdjango/ebdjango/views.py)

Inside dailytask/views.py (app folder)

```
from ebdjango.views import index
```

Inside ebdjango/views.py (main Django project folder)

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def index(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.userprofile.daily_task_done is False:
        return render(request, 'home.html')
    elif user.userprofile.daily_task_done is True:
        return task_done(request, pk=user.userprofile.daily_task)
```

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

[image: Structure]

What do I need to do to import the view Index into the app views.py?

Comment: Could you please provide your project structure and the files in the directories (At least the views.py and dunder inits.

Comment: https://monosnap.com/file/0RnMIV2JgScQsHQPxaZuwgES18pbe1

Here is an image of the whole structure

Comment: I have never put a `views.py` next to `settings.py`, Try one of these two things: 1. remove the decorator and see if it makes any difference 2. Move the `index` method to a `utils.py` file in an app

Comment: @9minday what are the imports listed in `ebdjango/views.py`? Can you share those?

Answer (score 0):

Do both `ebdjango/` and `dailytask/` folders have `__init__.py` files in them?

Comment: Yes they both have __init__.py in them

Comment: If you use Quotes around your `__init__.py` it will display the dunder and not make it bold.

Comment: Is there a dunder init file in the root dir?

Comment: That is weird, maybe post an image of your project file structure?

Comment: Here is a link to the image of the structure.
https://monosnap.com/file/0RnMIV2JgScQsHQPxaZuwgES18pbe1

Comment: what command are you running to get that error message? Also are you on windows?

Comment: I use OS Terminal. It comes up when I try to do python manage.py runserver. @MichaelCalve

Comment: Is that Mac OS?

Comment: It is weird because python recognizes the views.py file but not the function within it somehow, even though your code looks fine.

I'm not sure though. Good luck!

Comment: I would recommend using PyCharm as your IDE for creating your django app and using the terminal within PyCharm. The issue could be OS Terminal and PyCharm might help fix the situation